# Is there an official mechanism/algorithm for determining a youtube username or channel Id?

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-data-api

Given the changes brought about by Youtube's move to the V3 api, I'm wondering if theres an official way (without making API calls) to determine whether a value is a username or a channel id?

I've seen a few posts where people are suggesting if its prefixed with UC_ or HC_ then its a channel. But I've seen instances where the channel doesn't have the underscore and a username starts with UC.

E.g.

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJcYRr8rpsxVPfWA5vkuxFw
https://www.youtube.com/user/UCLA

If there isn't an official way of doing this, I was thinking that the check could involve the length of the string as well. So to that end, does anyone know in addition whether there is a length restriction on usernames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there appears to be a bit of a discrepancy around the length of usernames, but not the length of a channel id.

As such, I believe the following Regular Expression will suffice in determining whether the value is a channel id.

```
^UC.{22}$  # python
/^UC.{22}$/  // Javascript
```